# Is v8's --print-bytecode safe?

Tags: javascript, byte-code

I just saw [this post](https://medium.com/dailyjs/understanding-v8s-bytecode-317d46c94775), and I was wondering if it's safe to get v8 bytecode in that fashion with `--print-bytecode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `--print-bytecode` is not safe.

```
echo "process.exit(42)" > test.js
node --print-bytecode ./test.js
```

It exists with status_code = 42. So that code is getting executed. It is not safe.